Implementing mTLS on apache server with laravel on a subdomain
An institution we collaborate with has asked us to implement mutual TLS (mTLS) on a GET route they will be calling. On our server, we have added the following lines to the httpd.conf:
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 2

Above these lines, we have the following line:
SSLCertificateFile /.............../combined

In the combined file, we have the certificate authority (CA - in our case, it's R3 Let's Encrypt) at the bottom, the public key (.cert) in the middle, and the private key at the top (used for standard ssl).
The institution has provided us with a public certificate (.cert) issued by a different CA (DigiCert). From what I understand, we need to validate their certificate, and they need to validate ours. What should I configure to make this work, even at the subdomain level? Thank you.
With the current configuration, when I try to access the page in a browser, I get choose certificate popup.
I have also downloaded the DigiCert CA authority certificate and added a new line under SSLCertificateFile in the configuration:
SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/digicert/root_certificate.crt

However, this didn't work.

I think this is what you are looking for. See notes specifically on the CA pinning, too.
